# Django Download/Upload Files In Production

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django project that is currently hosted. I am serving static files but do not know how to handle user file uploads / downloads in the MEDIA folder. I've read a lot about Docker, Nginx, and Gunicorn but have no idea which I need nor how to set them up. I've followed no less than 20 tutorials and watched no less than 15 YouTube videos but am still confused (I've visited every link for the first 2 pages of all my Google searches).

My question is, which of these do I need to allow users to upload/download files from a site? On top of that, I have tried getting all three working but can't figure them out, surely I'm not the only one that has so much difficulty with this, is there a good resource/tutorial which would guide me through the process (I've spent well over 40 hours reading about this stuff and trying to get it to work, I've gotten to the point where so long as it works, I don't care for understanding how it all fits together)?

Thank you.

*edit* - this is a stripped down version of what was requested. I haven't included the html as it's my first time doing this and I've used Ajax and things and it's a complete mess and I'm sure will just confuse you.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_media')

STAT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ STAT,
                    os.path.join('static/'),
                    os.path.join('templates/static/'), # for overridden templates css
                    ]
```

view.py

```
class UploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        files_list = UploadedFile.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'users/modules.html', {'files': files_list})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        
        form = UploadedFileForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        form.instance.data_id = self.request.POST['data_id']

        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = form.save()
```

Thank you.

Comment: At this point, it's better to stop reading and start coding. Any file upload starts from the page with HTML form. So as a first step you need a Django view to display the page where a user can upload a file.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I have a website built already with user log in, etc. So I have figured out (with A LOT of help from people at StackOverflow) most of the problems I've come across (the transition from development to production server was particularly difficult). I have already made my page where users upload/download files, but as much as I read and code, I just cannot figure out how to server these in production. It works perfectly fine in my development environment.

Comment: Ok, then could you show: all STATIC* and MEDIA* settings, view responsible for file upload, html with upload form? Do you use docker/uwsgi/gunicorn/nginx already? If so please show me your Dockerfile and/or docker compose config.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev Sure. I added a much stripped down version of what you asked. I didn't include some stuff because this is my first time doing this and I've used Ajax and things so it's very very messy. I should add that this actually works on my development server, but I know I should be using something such as docker/uwsgi/gunicorn/nginx. And no, I have not implemented docker/uwsgi/gunicorn/nginx yet. Thank you.

Comment: Right there with you brother (or sister)! I've gotten uploading working, and into an `AWS S3 bucket` no less! That said, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the "upload info" to then display once the upload is complete. -sigh- But I'm work'en on it! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to know how to make your (*working in development environment*) project production-ready. Let's start with what components are required

1. Web Server (*Nginx*)
2. Application Server (*uWSGI*)
3. Application (*Django*)

**Web Server** serves the users' requests. It knows how to generate the correct output for a request - read a file from a filesystem, pass a request further to application server and so on. **Nginx** is the good choice.

**Application Server** is the middleman between *Web Server* and *Application*. It can spawn application instances (processes), balance the load between those instances, restart dead instances and many other things. **uWSGI** is good choice here.

**Application** - in your case it's Django project you have working in your development environment. You have everything ready here, but most likely you should adjust settings a bit. Django will communicate with *Application Server* through WSGI protocol.

---

At this point you should also understand how a web browser will load, render and display your site. All starts from a user who wants to open a page on your site, for example http://example.com/uploads. A browser will send HTTP GET request to your server and Web Server program (Nginx) will catch this request and decide what to do next.

Since that particular request isn't about some static file (static HTML file or static JPEG image and so on) - Nginx will decide to pass a request to Application Server. uWSGI will get the request and pass it forward to Django.

Django will use all the `urls.py` files to find the right view to generate the response for http://example.com/upload page. What your view will do?

```py
    def get(self, request):
        files_list = UploadedFile.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'users/modules.html', {'files': files_list})
```

it will return the HTML page (rendered template). So that HTML document will be returned back to Application Server, then back to Web Server and finally to a user's web browser.

Then a browser will start parsing of that HTML document and most likely it will find some additional resources to load - css, javascript, images, fonts, ... For each resource - it will make additional GET request to Web Server. And this time Web Server will not push requests forward to Application Server. It will just read those files from file system and return back to a browser.

Those resources are not dynamic, they are static. So you basically store them under `static` namespace. For example:

- http://example.com/static/main.css
- http://example.com/static/main.js
- http://example.com/static/logo.png
- ...

Those files are the part of your application. Your application is shipped with those files. But also there're some files which could be uploaded to your system. You could save those files in any place - filesystem, database, ... But you must have URLs for them. Usually it's `media` namespace:

- http://example.com/media/user-file.csv
- http://example.com/media/reports/john-02-12-2020.pdf
- ...

In both cases - those calls will be just forwarded to Web Server and then to filesystem.

Why do you see everything working on your development environment? It's likely because you run the application with `python manage.py runserver`. In that case - Django is your Web Server as well (and there will be no Application Server middleman). So it will manage it's own instances, it will get user's requests, it will return static files, it will return "media" files, it will return dynamically generated pages and so on.

---

Each component described above needs it's own configuration file. Let me show you some examples you can use for your project.

**Web Server** (*Nginx*)

`sites-enabled/default.conf`

```
upstream uwsgi {
  server uwsgi:8080;
}


server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  charset utf-8;

  location /media  {
      alias /home/web/media;
      expires 7d;
  }

  location /static {
      alias /home/web/static;
      expires 7d;
  }

  location / {
      uwsgi_pass uwsgi;
      include uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

Notes:

- everything under http://example.com/static will go to filesystem (`/home/web/static` directory)
- for example: http://example.com/static/css/main.css -> `/home/web/static/css/main.css`
- everything under http://example.com/media will go to filesystem (`/home/web/media` directory)
- for example: http://example.com/media/reports/john-02-12-2020.pdf -> `/home/web/media/reports/john-02-12-2020.pdf`
- everything else will be passed to uWSGI (to host `uwsgi`, to port `8080`)

**Application Server** (*uWSGI*)

`uwsgi.conf`

```
[uwsgi]

req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi-requests.log
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi-errors.log

workers = %k
# enable-threads = true
# threads = 4

chdir = /home/web/app
module = core.wsgi
master = true
pidfile=/tmp/app.pid
socket = 0.0.0.0:8080
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings
memory-report = true
harakiri = 60
listen = 10240
```

Notes:

- `chdir = /home/web/app` - it's the path to your application
- `module = core.wsgi` - your application should have directory with main (core) application called `core` (you should see `wsgi.py` there)
- `pidfile=/tmp/app.pid` - just a place for pid file
- `socket = 0.0.0.0:8080` - it will listen port `8080`
- `env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings` - again, you need main app to be called `core` (it should be inside `core` directory) and you should have `settings.py` inside it)

**Docker / Docker Compose**

You might need Docker and Docker Compose to orchestrate all that software. But it's possible to try run everything without it as well.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.4"

services:

  uwsgi:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: uwsgi
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: 10240
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=${C_FORCE_ROOT}
    volumes:
      - ./config/uwsgi/uwsgi.conf:/uwsgi.conf
      - ../app:/home/web/app
      - ./static:/home/web/static:rw
      - ./media:/home/web/media:rw
      - ./logs:/var/log/
    restart: always
    networks:
      myapp_backend:
        aliases:
          - uwsgi

  web:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: 10240
    depends_on:
      - uwsgi
    volumes:
      # - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./config/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./media:/home/web/media:ro
      - ./static:/home/web/static:ro
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      # - "443:443"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - myapp_backend

networks:
  myapp_backend:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9.0

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl

RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing && apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip install uwsgi

WORKDIR /home/web/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "/uwsgi.conf"]
```

**Directory Structure**

You can use directory structure from this repository: https://github.com/ansysy24/GameEconomy/tree/master/deployment

Also I highly recommend this article https://andrey-borzenko.medium.com/simple-nginx-uwsgi-daphne-reactive-application-part-1-the-big-picture-20d7b9ee5b96

And don't forget to add `.env` file like this one https://github.com/ansysy24/GameEconomy/blob/master/deployment/.env_template (but you should rename ofc)

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help. There is a lot to take in and implement into my project. I will get back to you after at least a day, as I will need that much time to get it working. Thanks again. I'll give you an update once it's implemented :)

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear that, Brenden. Feel free to contact me should you have any questions.

Comment: could you please advise why `enable-threads` in `uwsgi.conf` was commented out? thanks,